# why do i get citation messages?

Tags: pdftex, citing, undefined, structure, legrandorangebook

This is the main file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning}
\tikzset{block/.style={draw,thick,text width=2cm,minimum height=1cm,align=center},
    line/.style={-latex}
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage[boxruled,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}
%--------------------------------------

\input{structure}
\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%--------------------------------------

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\endgroup
%--------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS
%---------------------------------------

\chapterimage{chapter_head_1.pdf} 

\pagestyle{empty} 
\tableofcontents
    \listoftables
    \listoffigures
\cleardoublepage 
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\part{Part One}
%----------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 1
%---------------------------------------

\chapterimage{chapter_head_1.pdf}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\input{ch1.tex}

% more chapters are included

%--------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------
\chapterimage{chapter_head_1.pdf}
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{blue}{Bibliography}}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\addbibresource{References.bib} 
\printbibliography

%---------------------------------------
%   INDEX
%----------------------------------------

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.75cm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{blue}{Index}}
\printindex

%---------------------------------------

\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Why do I get multiple citation related messages like the one below? Besides the document also does not get displayed. I have provided the main and structure file for reference. I have compiled using pdfLaTex in overleaf.

1. Citation '1.1' on page 2 undefined on input line 10.
   &
2. Command @parboxrestore has changed.

Typical entry in References.bib

```
@book{1.1,
  title={Routing in the Internet},
  author={Huitema, Christian},
  year={1995},
  publisher={Prentice-Hall, Inc.}
}
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

The structure file looks like below:

```
%-----------------------------------
%   VARIOUS REQUIRED PACKAGES AND CONFIGURATIONS
%--------------------------------

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist{nolistsep} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{243,102,25} 
-------------------------------------------
%   FONTS
--------------------------------------------
\usepackage{avant} 
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

-----------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY AND INDEX
----------------------------------
\usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,autolang=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib} 
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}
\usepackage{calc} 
\usepackage{imakeidx} 
\makeindex 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! Please reduce your input to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to help us to answer.

Comment: Too lazy to puzzle all your code pieces together and deal with all the missing files, but `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}` is not a biblatex macros.

Comment: Thank You @JosephWright. I have reduced the code size and have managed to keep the codes relevant to bibliography. Thank You.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz are you suggesting something else apart from \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}?

Comment: A minimal example is one we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the issue. It doesn't depend on files we don't have.

Comment: If you use Biblatex, you don't need `\bibliographystyle`. If you use `\bibliographystyle`, don't load Biblatex.

Comment: @SDe Yes, remove it. And then reduce your code further so we can reproduce the problem without needing all your external files.

Comment: you should make your example _much_ smaller before posting here but you should make it smaller in your real document as well:  you specify multiple packages multiple times (tikz, float, xcolor,fontenc) , you specify packages that are clearly incompatible, eg enumitem and enumerate both define enumerate environment so you can not load both. You should remove packages that are never needed now (inputenc, latexsym, epstopdf, morefloats)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i commented packages not needed ever including repetitions of packages you mentioned and commented out enumerate package in main. After compiling it gives: 1) Undefined control sequence and 2) Missing \begin{document} for the code:    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning}  \tikzset{block/.style={draw,thick,text width=2cm,minimum height=1cm,align=center}, line/.style={-latex}
}      why am i getting this? Is it expecting this code to be after \begin{document}? In this comment i gave small portion of code - is the size ok? In real document i commented out those lines.

Comment: Also, citation comments like:   Citation '1.1' on page 2 undefined on input line 10.  are still there